# vuetify, v-card-subtitle :title ... what does this do?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am studying a project that uses a lot of Vuetify and `v-card` components. One such component is `<v-card-subtitle>` which is used like this-

```
<v-card-subtitle :title="display.content">
  Hello World
</v-card-subtitle>
```

When I hover over `v-card-subtitle`, `:title` displays a small popup, I want to style this popup but it looks like an inherent Vuetify property, maybe?

What is `:title` and how does it work? Is anyone familiar with this? I can't find this in the documentation.

I want to style `:title` specifically, not the `v-card-subtitle`. I've tried the following ways-

- Wrapping the title in a `span` and `div`
- Adding addition classes or subclasses

But, no such luck.

Comment: What is the Vuetify version?

Comment: Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve]. Also, specify ***in clear*** what it is you want to achieve. *"I want to style `:title`"* is an unrealistic requirement, because `:title` is an attribute of a component, therefore it can't be styled. You probably want to style the DOM element which the component creates (having the `:title` attribute's value as content). Please be more specific about your request, to the point where it can't be misinterpreted or misunderstood.

Comment: `:title` is undocumented on [`<v-card-subtitle>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-card-subtitle/). Based on docs, you shouldn't even expect it to work.

Comment: @tao thank you for the response, that did answer a lot of my question. Now I know that :title is not a documented attribute of <v-card-subtitle>. My next question is, whats the best way to create a popup box when hovering over a v-card component? thanks!

Comment: @vernou Vuetify version 1.12.3

Comment: wow that is old.  they don't even have [documentation for that version](https://v1.vuetifyjs.com/) available anymore.  you should 100% upgrade to at least v2.x.  I doubt many people could help debug _anything_ from vuetify 1.12

Answer (score 3):

Oh, that's just the regular [HTML title attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) bound to a variable by Vue. Vue can bind variables to any HTML attribute using `v-bind` or the shorthand `:` syntax, not just component props.

Note that if an attribute is not bound by a component, it is pushed down to the component's root element. Vue calls this [Fallthough Attributes](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html).

So your `v-card-subtitle` renders a div with a HTML title attribute, set to the value in `display.content`. And yes, native titles cannot be styled.

But you could replace them with Vuetify's [`v-tooltip`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/). Those you can style, change placement, and they overall fit nicely with other Vuetify components.

Comment: @mortitz-ringler Thank you so much, this answer makes a lot of sense. I had a feeling I couldn't style the HTML title attribute. Do you know a way to create the same effect, to hover over v-card-subtitle, and be able to style a text popup? tia!

Comment: @PnwDev77 Oh, that's a good point, I could have thought of mentioning Vuetify's v-tooltip. Have a look at them, they are pretty nice. I have added a link in the answer.